# Is removing elements from an ArrayList or LinkedList while iterating through it with a for loop in Java bad? If so, why?

Tags: java, list, iterator, concurrentmodification

I was showing my code to someone and they said that it would cause undefined behavior.  Being a Java programmer, that's not something I understand well.  In the following code block I am iterating through `scenes`, which is an ArrayList, and removing elements from it.

```
for(int i = 0; i < scenes.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        if(!(Double.valueOf(scenes.get(i + 1)) - Double.valueOf(scenes.get(i)) > 10))
        {
            scenes.remove(i + 1);
            i--;
        }
    }
```

This compiles and doesn't throw an exception at runtime, but I'm still not sure if it's a programming no-no, why it's a programming no-no, and what is the right way to do it.  I've heard about using `Iterator.remove()` and about just creating a whole new `List`.

Comment: There's several things to unpack here. First of all, index-based access of Linked List takes `O(i)` time, because to get to a particular index you must go through each node starting from its head (or tail, whichever is closest, assuming it has this optimization). Generally speaking, better way to iterate over lists is to use its `Iterator`, because it would be implemented in best way possible according to internal implementation.

Comment: Then, when you do use the `Iterator`, it's going to throw `ConcurrentModificationException` after you modify the list - after modifications, most iterators in created prior to the modification become stale and throw exceptions if you use them in that state. `Iterator.remove()` doesn't make that particular iterator stale, but will make all other iterators stale.

Comment: @jnorman, that's a question about python, not necessarily Java.

Answer (score 1):

In an `ArrayList`, removing an element from the middle of the list requires you to shift all of the elements with a higher index down by one. This is fine if you do it once (or a small number of times), but inefficient if you do it repeatedly.

You don't really want to use an `Iterator` for this either, because `Iterator.remove()` suffers from the same issue.

A better approach to this is to go through the list, moving the elements you want to keep to their new positions; and then just remove the tail of the list at the end:

```
int dst = 0;
for (int src = 0; src < scenes.size(); ++dst) {
  // You want to keep this element.
  scenes.set(dst, scenes.get(src++));

  // Now walk along the list until you find the element you want to keep.
  while (src < scenes.size()
         && Double.parseDouble(scenes.get(src)) - Double.parseDouble(scenes.get(dst)) <= 10) {
    // Increment the src pointer, so you won't keep the element.
    ++src;
  }
}

// Remove the tail of the list in one go.
scenes.subList(dst, scenes.size()).clear();
```

(This "shift and clear" approach is what is used by `ArrayList.removeIf`; you can't use that directly here because you can't inspect adjacent elements in the list, you only have access to the current element).

---

You can take a similar approach which will also work efficiently with non-random access lists such as `LinkedList`. You need to avoid repeatedly calling `get` and `set`, since these are e.g. `O(size)` in the case of `LinkedList`.

In that case, you would use `ListIterator` instead of plain indexes:

```
ListIterator<String> dst = scenes.listIterator();
for (ListIterator<String> src = scenes.listIterator(); src.hasNext();) {
  dst.next();
  String curr = src.next();
  dst.set(curr);

  while (src.hasNext()
         && Double.parseDouble(src.next()) - Double.parseDouble(curr) <= 10) {}
}
scenes.subList(dst.nextIndex(), scenes.size()).clear();
```

Or something like this. I've not tested it, and `ListIterator` is always pretty confusing to use.

Comment: Need to note that the question isn't just about `ArrayList`, but also about `LinkedList`. This implementation of shift approach doesn't work well with linked lists, because of index-based access, but will work better if using two iterators.

Comment: Ok I've read over your answer a few times and while I'm still working on understanding some of it, I just wanted to mention that while I was researching about this I came across a Carnegie Mellon University Page that said the following.
"According to the Java API documentation for the Iterator.remove() method: The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this method".  This seems to Indicate that using Iterator shouldn't suffer from the same issue that you mentioned at the beginning.

Comment: @brendanw36 it doesn't say that at all. What that's saying isn't even related to using the `Iterator.remove()` method, it's talking about using `List.remove` whilst also iterating.

Comment: @brendanw36 an easy way to convince yourself that removing from an `ArrayList` with `Iterator.remove()` is inefficient: create a list of size n (e.g. `new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(size, 0))`); time how long it takes to remove everything from it with `for (Iterator<?> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext(); it.next(), it.remove());` (removing from the start), compare that to `while (!list.isEmpty()) list.remove(list.size() - 1);` (removing from the end). Try n=1000000.

Comment: @AndyTurner so access to an Array is O(1), but insertion and deletion are O(n).  Access to a LinkedList is O(n), but insertion and deletion are O(1).  Are you saying that I can have the best of both worlds by using a LinkedList with a ListIterator for access?

Comment: There's no free lunch. You get cheap deletion for a `LinkedList`; but you also get really slow everything else, because of the lack of locality.

Answer (score 0):

This is straightforward and will work for either ArrayList or LinkedList:

```
        Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
        double current = 0;
        double next;
        boolean firstTime = true;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            if (firstTime) {
                current = Double.parseDouble(iterator.next());
                firstTime = false;
            } else {
                next = Double.parseDouble(iterator.next());
                if (next - current > 10) {
                    current = next;
                } else {
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }
        }
```